# AndroidPlot - Position TextLabelWidget not consistently on different devices

Tags: androidplot

I have a chart show info of apps, but when run it on devices android. The position of text on chart not consistently.

These images illustrate the problem: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7-CxJHQ5ZnjYjVlTlFQdElWRGM&usp=sharing

I use TextLabelWidget in AndroidPlot. How to keep position of TextLabelWidget on chart with the same image1 in link above on devices?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that your plot area is set to fill the width of the screen and since the bars are evenly distributed in that space, their x positions are essentially fractions of the screen width.

At the same time you have labels that appear to be positioned using absolute positioning.  As an example, this code will position 4 labels at 0%, 25%, 50% and 75% screen width, 80 pixels down from the top of the screen:

```
txtWidget1.position(0, XLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_LEFT, PixelUtils.dpToPix(80), YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP, AnchorPosition.LEFT_TOP);
txtWidget2.position(0.25f, XLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_LEFT, PixelUtils.dpToPix(80), YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP, AnchorPosition.LEFT_TOP);
txtWidget3.position(0.50f, XLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_LEFT, PixelUtils.dpToPix(80), YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP, AnchorPosition.LEFT_TOP);
txtWidget4.position(0.75f, XLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_LEFT, PixelUtils.dpToPix(80), YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP, AnchorPosition.LEFT_TOP);
```

There are some other factors that you are also probably going to need to deal with such as bar width but this should get you closer.  You may find [this doc](http://androidplot.com/docs/styling-your-plot/) useful as far as a guide for the different positioning methods.

Another tool to consider using if you aren't using it already is [the Configurator](http://androidplot.com/docs/xml-styling-with-configurator/).  This will let you set your positions etc. inside xml and override values based on screen size, orientation, etc.

Comment: Thank Nick, but it not work for me. The position of text on chart still not consistently. Because position of text dependence position of each column. Do you suggest for this?

Comment: There's no easy solution; like I said, there are other factors involved including how you are defining the width of your bars etc. which will make it very difficult to get a completely consistent look across devices. The best advice I can give would be *not* to try to use TextLabelWidget in this way but instead override BarRenderer to do what you want [as outlined here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091390/androidplot-labels-and-text).

Comment: Nick, I tried implement with your suggestion in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091390/androidplot-labels-and-text, it really better than before. But position of $35,234.00 still not same on columns. As you can see here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7-CxJHQ5ZnjOVlGeHFnVkdhT1k&usp=sharing. The reason of this is function canvas.translate(x,y), but i really undo the translate with canvas.translate(-x,-y) after drawText "$35,234.00" but still not right. Do you suggestion in this case?

Comment: Is your translate nested within a call to canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG); and canvas.restore()?  If so, the restore() already reverts your original translate and canvas.translate(-x,-y) is unnecessary.  Also, have you tried logging the x value being passed into this translate to ensure that it's not decreasing on each subsequent call?

Comment: I updated [my response in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091390/androidplot-labels-and-text) with code examples and screenshots that might be helpful.  While doing so it occurred to me that your problem could be caused by invoking Canvas.drawText(..., x, y) instead of Canvas.drawText(..., 0, 0).